# Weird error when using fread with struct

Tags: c, fread, bmp

So, I was trying to read a BMP image using fread and structs. I create the following struct to read the header

```
struct head{
char sigBM[2];//This will get the 'B' and 'M' chars
int fileSize;
int reserved;
int offset
...
};
```

And in the main function I used

```
fread(pointerToStruct,sizeof(struct head),1,image);
```

And I just got some weird results. But then I decided to take the char sigBM[2] from the struct and read it with a different fread. Something like:

```
char sigBM[2];
struct head *p = malloc(sizeof(struct head));/*
Without the char sigBM[2]
*/
fread(sigBM,sizeof(char),2,image);
fread(p,sizeof(struct head),1,image);
```

And it worked!

I already got it working, I just want to know why it worked like that

Comment: `struct head` probably has some padding in it: two unused bytes between `sigBM` and `fileSize`, that nonetheless take up space, and thus consume two bytes you weren't expecting in your read. You may be able to tell your compiler not to pad this struct; I have no experience with that, though.

Comment: Make sure the `sizeof(struct head)` is the same as the file as the `sizeof(struct head)` in you code.

Answer (score 2):

Your data seem to be written to disk without padding. That is; that integer `fileSize` comes directly after the two chars. This is normally not how structs are kept in memory.

the size of

```
struct head{
  char sigBM[2];//This will get the 'B' and 'M' chars
  // two padding bytes hide here
  int fileSize;
}
```

is 8 on my machine. not 2+4 as you may expect. If you read/write with the same compiler options on the same platform you can expect the struct to be read in correctly. If not, you need to be in control of details like these.

Most architectures require (or prefer) that numeric types start at specific multipliers of two [for example the size of the type itself].

Answer (score 0):

In a 16-bit `int`, 32-bit `long` world with

```
struct head{
  char sigBM[2];
  long fileSize;
  long reserved;
  long offset
  ...
};
```

all works well.  But try to read with a struct that has padding (extra space between fields) causes OP's issue.

A solution is to read each field, one at a time - like OP's approach.  Another approach is to use a compiler specific option or keyword to "pack" the structure.

---

In general, given C variant `int` size, better to use think of these fields as `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t` rather than `char`, `int`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
the OP has workable idea.  It does need some extension.

Of some note is that several fields within the .bmp file
have non-fixed offsets from the start of the file.
so a single struct will not properly handle the whole file

Of critical interest is the number of 'special' color entries
as that changes the offsets for all the rest of the file.

the actual image, depending on the pixel width and the image width
can have from 0 to 3 bytes of filler for each pixel line of the image

certain fields are optional in the second section of the file.
and some fields within the first section of the file contain 
offsets into the file for other key areas.

in general, it is best to treat the file as a long string of bytes
and use offsets (and field length) to access specific fields 

this has been demonstrated, with full C code, 
on several answers in stackoverflow.com

suggest performing a search.
```